# How to improve lm output obtained with for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression, lm

I made a for loop in order to evaluate multiple models using the same Y and different X. 
Using mtcars database I create two subsets:

```
mcars1 <- subset(mtcars, select=c("mpg","hp","disp"))
mcars2 <- subset(mtcars, select=c("mpg","disp"))
```

The for loop is the following

```
for (var in c("mcars1", "mcars2")){
    v <- get(var)
    reg <- lm(mpg~., data=v)
    print(summary(reg)$coef)
}
```

Output:

```
               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 30.73590425 1.331566129 23.082522 3.262507e-20
hp          -0.02484008 0.013385499 -1.855746 7.367905e-02
disp        -0.03034628 0.007404856 -4.098159 3.062678e-04
               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 29.59985476 1.229719515 24.070411 3.576586e-21
disp        -0.04121512 0.004711833 -8.747152 9.380327e-10
```

As you can see, everything is ok. I just wanna know which functions I can use in order to improve my ouput, for example to get something like:

```
Model 1
               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 30.73590425 1.331566129 23.082522 3.262507e-20***
hp          -0.02484008 0.013385499 -1.855746 7.367905e-02***
disp        -0.03034628 0.007404856 -4.098159 3.062678e-04***


Model 2  
               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 29.59985476 1.229719515 24.070411 3.576586e-21***
disp        -0.04121512 0.004711833 -8.747152 9.380327e-10***
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: store the results in a list? e.g. `results[[var]] <- summary(reg)$coef`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(list(mcars1,mcars2),function(x)coef(summary(lm(x))))
[[1]]
               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 30.73590425 1.331566129 23.082522 3.262507e-20
hp          -0.02484008 0.013385499 -1.855746 7.367905e-02
disp        -0.03034628 0.007404856 -4.098159 3.062678e-04

[[2]]
               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 29.59985476 1.229719515 24.070411 3.576586e-21
disp        -0.04121512 0.004711833 -8.747152 9.380327e-10
```

or you can do:

```
 lapply(list(mcars1,mcars2),function(x)coef(summary(lm(mpg~.,dat=x))))
```